# Notepad++ assumes .txt file extension when loading from a command line

Tags: notepad++

I have a file called `Dockerfile` in my directory:

[image]

I'm attempting to edit that file in Notepad++, so I type the command:

```
notepad Dockerfile
```

Notepad++ comes up, but it tries to open a file called `Dockerfile.txt` which doesn't exist:

[image]

Is there a way to configure Notepad++ to load the file given at the command line, and not assume it has any particular extension?  Thanks!

**Note:** On my machine, Notepad.exe has been [overwritten to point to Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/replace-notepad.html).

Comment: VS Code may be better to work on Dockerfile. It recognizes the format and does syntax highlighting on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The standard filename for Notepad++ is `Notepad++.exe`, no `notepad.exe`. The last is the Windows standard notepad. So try

   ```
   notepad++ Dockerfile
   ```
2. If it doesn't help, *append the filename with the period (`.`):*

   ```
   notepad++ Dockerfile.
   ```

   or - if your filename for Notepad++ is nevertheless `notepad.exe`:

   ```
   notepad Dockerfile.
   ```

Comment: Cool, that appears to work!  But it'll take me a long time to get used to doing that hahah

Comment: Note: On my machine, notepad.exe has been [overwritten to point to notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/replace-notepad.html).  But yes, you're right, by default this is `notepad++.exe`

Answer (score 4):

Did a bit more research on this, and this appears to be by design.  This actually does *not* repro if you run Notepad++ the normal way, using `notepad++ Dockerfile` instead of overriding the `Image File Execution` in the registry.  Notepad++ has some code in the [convertParamsToNotepadStyle method](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/ab4cf883367eb3818fc0e6dea57d39d21f9ec618/PowerEditor/src/winmain.cpp#L119) which basically *mimics* what Windows Notepad does by default, which is to add a `.txt` extension by default.

So, what causes Notepad++ to mimic Notepad?  It turns out to be the `-notepadStyleCmdline` parameter, which is [included in the instructions](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/replace-notepad.html) on how to replace Notepad.  If you remove the parameter and override Notepad like so:

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "\"%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\" -z" /f
```

Then Notepad++ will behave like Notepad++.